# Updating gradle results in 'Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig.getBuildConfigPackageName()Ljava/lang/String'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I update
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
to
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'

I am getting this error.  I am not sure how I can find the dependencies that may be causing this issue.  For a while I have just been sticking to 3.6.3.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably caused by a gradle plugin that you are using which is relying on a task that is renamed/removed/replaced in version 4.

To find out what causes it, do a `gradlew -S buildDebug` from the root for your project to get a verbose error stack.
Also make sure to do a `gradlew clean` to make sure that gradle cache is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks!  I have found heap analytics was the culprit in my case... update the client and gradle dependencies to 1.7.1 if you see this error

Comment: @dollarmide what do you mean gradle dependencies 1.7.1,  `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.7.1"`?